# Concatenar valores de un mismo campo

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo una consulta que me trae estos datos,como ven me trae las mismas tareas porque tiene 2 usuarios que la manejan, quiero que me ayuden a concatenarla

[image]

De manera que quede como esta otra y así me reduzca lo registros que no es necesario que traiga

[image]

Aquí tengo parte de la consulta donde supongo que debo hacer la concatenación estoy utilizando MySQL

```
select  
B.bandeja
,a.bandejaTareaId as TareaID
,A.userid as 'Usuario Reporta'
,E.username as 'Usuario Bandeja'
,A.inicio
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías agrupar por TareaID:

```
select group_concat(e.username) AS 'Usuario Bandeja' 
from tablas
group by TareaID
```

Comment: 2/2 eh preguntado 2 veces cosas distintas y tus respuestas en 2 ocaciones me salvaron,soy nuevo en esto y tengo mucho que aprender gracias men.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar esta función `CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT CONCAT("SQL ", "Tutorial ", "is ", "fun!") AS ConcatenatedString;
```

[Referencia.](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agruparlo por TareaID. Ejemplo:

```
"SELECT B.bandeja ,a.bandejaTareaId as TareaID ,A.userid as 'Usuario Reporta' , GROUP_CONCAT(E.username) AS 'Usuario Bandeja', A.inicio
FROM table
GROUP BY a.bandejaTareaId"
```